# Guarded blocks in Java. Where should I update a condition variable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd use a `volatile` condition variable, but I think `volatile` is redundant. Besides I'm not quite sure I understood this point from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility correctly:

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor
>   happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method
>   entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation
>   is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking
>   happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that
>   monitor.

So `synchronized` blocks are called subsequently. But are results of assignments performed in a `synchronized` block visible to all the subsequent `synchronized` blocks?

Here is a sample app.

```
package sample;

public class Foo {

    private boolean shouldWait;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    void blockThread() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            shouldWait = true;
            while (shouldWait) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void notifyThread() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            shouldWait = false;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Test.

```
package sample;

public class Main {

    private static Foo foo = new Foo();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo.blockThread();
            }
        }).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo.notifyThread();
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So synchronized blocks are called subsequently. But are results of assignments performed in a synchronized block visible to all the subsequent synchronized blocks?

Yes. `volatile` writes have the same relationship.  All actions prior to a `volatile` write happens-before all subsequent reads.

Comment: Thanks. But do you have a link to the official documentation which can prove your answer?

Comment: *A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do not entail mutual exclusion locking.*  It's from your link.